# SAS : Understanding lag function to retain dates based on work progess

Tags: sas, lag, retain

I have a work progress sheet to make.
So if we have a table with work progress as new, progress, start, end and restart and some Rules were:

1. First, when work is NEW, start date set as '1/01/2013' and other following work_progress set same.
2. Second, if work is END-ed and again ADD-ed,start date is set as '01/01/2016' (Below: Work_id=3). The following work_progress must have same value.
3. Last case, when work (work_id:1,2) RESTARTs, start date is set beginning of work received. The later dates must follow same
   '01/05/2017'. Below is the dataset outputted with my logic.

text -indent

```
+---------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| work_id | work_progress |   received_date   |   start    |    end     |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
|       1 | NEW           | November 19, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       1 | PROGRESS      | December 25, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       1 | END           | January 1, 2017   | 01/01/2013 | 02/02/2017 |
|       1 | RESTART       | February 5, 2017  | 01/05/2017 | 31/12/2020 |
|       1 | PROGRESS      | March 20, 2017    | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | NEW           | November 19, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | PROGRESS      | December 25, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | END           | January 1, 2017   | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | RESTART       | February 5, 2017  | 01/05/2017 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | PROGRESS      | March 20, 2017    | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       3 | NEW           | November 19, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       3 | END           | December 25, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 02/02/2017 |
|       3 | NEW           | January 1, 2017   | 01/01/2016 | 31/12/2020 |
|       3 | END           | February 5, 2017  | 01/01/2013 | 02/02/2017 |
|       3 | END           | March 20, 2017    | 01/01/2013 | 03/03/2017 |
|       3 | END           | April 21, 2017    | 01/01/2013 | 04/04/2017 |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

What i actually what my output to be:

```
+---------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| work_id | work_progress |   received_date   |   start    |    end     |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
|       1 | NEW           | November 19, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       1 | PROGRESS      | December 25, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       1 | END           | January 1, 2017   | 01/01/2013 | 02/02/2017 |
|       1 | RESTART       | February 5, 2017  | 01/05/2017 | 31/12/2020 |
|       1 | PROGRESS      | March 20, 2017    | 01/05/2017 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | NEW           | November 19, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | PROGRESS      | December 25, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | END           | January 1, 2017   | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | RESTART       | February 5, 2017  | 01/05/2017 | 31/12/2020 |
|       2 | PROGRESS      | March 20, 2017    | 01/05/2017 | 31/12/2020 |
|       3 | NEW           | November 19, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2020 |
|       3 | END           | December 25, 2016 | 01/01/2013 | 02/02/2017 |
|       3 | NEW           | January 1, 2017   | 01/01/2016 | 31/12/2020 |
|       3 | END           | February 5, 2017  | 01/01/2016 | 02/02/2017 |
|       3 | END           | March 20, 2017    | 01/01/2016 | 02/02/2017 |
|       3 | END           | April 21, 2017    | 01/01/2016 | 02/02/2017 |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

Requirement:

1. Start date should be added to later work progress when NEW and
   RESTART.
2. In end date in work_id=3 and work_progress= END. The march and april
   both should have end date that of feb.

I require to use lag here to retain the start and end dates. I already have implemented half of my problem's logic except this lag usage part.
Part of sas code:

```
data m_out_ds;
 set m_in_ds;
 by work_id work_received_date;
 /*--------
 Some logic to derive my rules, that gave output, first table above.
  ----------*/
 prevstart = lag(start);
 prevend = lag(end); 
 prev_work_progress = lag(work_progress);

 if work_progress = 'END' and prev_work_progress = 'END' then end = prevend;

/*---This gave 02/02/2017 for march received date only, 
  but we require for april too, obvious the work has ended.----*/

if work_progress = 'PROGRESS' and prev_work_progress ='RESTART' 
  then start = prevstart; 

/*---This however worked---*/

run;
```

Let me know if you've trouble understanding this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just use retained variables instead of trying to get LAG() function to help?

Comment: Hi @tom ! Sorting by work_id and recieved_date doesn't allow to get help from retain here.

Comment: Is the first set of data the input? Or some attempt at the output? If not can you post the input.

Comment: @tom, some attempt at the output. I'm afraid I can't do that now. Does the indent make things clearer? I want second table from first, that's it.

Comment: Can you explain the rules using the example data? Why does START change from 2013-01-01 to 2017-05-01 in row 5 (the last row for the first ID value)?  Where does that new date come from? Is it because it was the start on the previous record? Or did it matter that the previous record had type of RESTART?  Does it matter that the previous value was AFTER the current value for START on record 5?

Comment: Apologizes for not being that descriptive. Take this as part of rule, if a work ends and again restarts, we should start effective from the 'received_date' month on wards. Refer received that as the file date, so please consider this while sorting to know the work_progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to match your data, but I still not sure I understand the rules. First let's make your text into data.

```
data have ;
  infile cards dsd dlm='|' truncover ;
  row+1;
  length work_id 8 work_progress $8 received_date start end 8 ;
  informat received_date anydtdte. start end ddmmyy.;
  format received_date  start end yymmdd10.;
  input work_id -- end ;
CARDS;
   1|NEW     | November 19, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   1|PROGRESS| December 25, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   1|END     | January 1, 2017  |01/01/2013|02/02/2017 
   1|RESTART | February 5, 2017 |01/05/2017|31/12/2020 
   1|PROGRESS| March 20, 2017   |01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   2|NEW     | November 19, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   2|PROGRESS| December 25, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   2|END     | January 1, 2017  |01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   2|RESTART | February 5, 2017 |01/05/2017|31/12/2020 
   2|PROGRESS| March 20, 2017   |01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   3|NEW     | November 19, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   3|END     | December 25, 2016|01/01/2013|02/02/2017 
   3|NEW     | January 1, 2017  |01/01/2016|31/12/2020 
   3|END     | February 5, 2017 |01/01/2013|02/02/2017 
   3|END     | March 20, 2017   |01/01/2013|03/03/2017 
   3|END     | April 21, 2017   |01/01/2013|04/04/2017 
;
data want ;
  infile cards dsd dlm='|' truncover ;
  row+1;
  length work_id 8 work_progress $8 received_date start end 8 ;
  informat received_date anydtdte. start end ddmmyy.;
  format received_date  start end yymmdd10.;
  input work_id -- end ;
CARDS;
   1|NEW        |November 19, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   1|PROGRESS   |December 25, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   1|END        |January 1, 2017  |01/01/2013|02/02/2017 
   1|RESTART    |February 5, 2017 |01/05/2017|31/12/2020 
   1|PROGRESS   |March 20, 2017   |01/05/2017|31/12/2020 
   2|NEW        |November 19, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   2|PROGRESS   |December 25, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   2|END        |January 1, 2017  |01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   2|RESTART    |February 5, 2017 |01/05/2017|31/12/2020 
   2|PROGRESS   |March 20, 2017   |01/05/2017|31/12/2020 
   3|NEW        |November 19, 2016|01/01/2013|31/12/2020 
   3|END        |December 25, 2016|01/01/2013|02/02/2017 
   3|NEW        |January 1, 2017  |01/01/2016|31/12/2020 
   3|END        |February 5, 2017 |01/01/2016|02/02/2017 
   3|END        |March 20, 2017   |01/01/2016|02/02/2017 
   3|END        |April 21, 2017   |01/01/2016|02/02/2017 
;
```

Now let's try to convert it.

```
data try ;
  set have ;
  by work_id;
  retain new_start new_end ;
  format new_start new_end yymmdd10.;
  if first.work_id then call missing(of new_start new_end);
  if work_progress in ('NEW','RESTART') then new_start=start ;
  start=coalesce(new_start,start);
  if work_progress in ('END') then do;
    if missing(new_end) then new_end=end ;
    end=coalesce(new_end,end);
  end;
run;
proc compare data=want compare=try;
  id row;
run;
proc print data=try; run;
```

[image]

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. The output is what i look for. But, if i can make you understand how the received_date is linked with work_id,i could be sure this works perfectly. All the ids 1,2,3 were received with corresponding status on 2016-11-19 (November 19, 2016), and works are received monthly. The work life cycle : NEW-PROGRESS-END-<RESTART>/<NEW>-END and so. If you get this, the logic would be more reasonable. Are you getting me? Thanks for your help here.